# jBPM Workbench Docker failed after successfully accessed previously

Tags: java, docker, jbpm

I'm new to `jBPM Workbench` I've already installed `jBPM Workbench docker` latest version and successfully accessed the `http://localhost:8080/business-central`.

But today when I want to open the `docker` there is an error at startup and after I restore to default version and re-run the command:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 8001:8001 -d --name jbpm-workbench jboss/jbpm-workbench:latest
```

This script downloads and pulls the image again and after completed, the link still can not be accessed.

**Anyone knows:**

1. Why the docker error after successfully accessed? is it because i didn't shutdown/kill this docker previously?
2. How is the best practice to maintain the current container in my
   docker? so that I do not need to restore the docker and re-run again the above script?
3. How to solve this problem? I will try to uninstall the docker now and doing the installation again. Hopefully it works, but appreciate if you can suggest me the better troubleshoot for it.

Answer (score 1):

### Answers:

1. What is the Error on startup and what is that startup? Sis you stop the docker container and or pc where it is running, in meantime?
2. You should not restore the docker with new "run". `Docker stop "created container name- in your case jbpm-workbench"` and `docker start jbpm-workbench` should work properly.
3. Docker is separate application and it is robust one, as it runs virtual machines and processes. If there a problem starting Docker, first check if you have provided enough RAM memory, at least 2GB. I am not sure how much jboss configured image of KIE needs but probably at least 1GB. So in docker settings you need 2GB dedicated to this container only.

I hope this is good for start to get you back on track.